# How do you manage your list of CSS files for each View?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc-2

So, guys, there's no secret for each of you that every view has certain list of CSS and JS files. There can be global scope files and corresponding for each view files that's required by only one view. So how do you guys manage CSS and JS list in your MVC project? Please advice me something efficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases you would want to define your list of CSS and JS files within the master file appropriate for the view in question.

If however you have CSS/JS files that should only be included within a specific view, you may set up a content placeholder in your master file, and override it in your view. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144088/how-to-pass-pages-meta-tags-in-asp-net-mvc) may in that case be interesting for you.

Regarding placement, I like to put all my CSS files in the content-folder that is generated for me when I create a new ASP.NET MVC project: project-name/content/css

JS files i put in the scripts directory: project-name/scripts

This way, there's never any doubt on where to put new CSS/JS files, and the project structure stays organized and uncluttered.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But what you would do in case if you need some extra logic like "script1.js need to go before script2.js" and script2.js is defined in master page?